# Create single list from list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

From `data = ["1,2","3,4"]` I'm attempting to create a list of strings :  `["1","2","3","4"]`

Trying this code :

```
comb = []
for x in data:
    for(y in x.split(',')):
        comb.append(y)
```

returns :

```
  File "<ipython-input-46-20897dcf51a1>", line 4
    for(y in x.split(',')):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As `x.split(',')` return a list of the parsed elements , in this context it should be a valid for loop ?

Comment: Remove the outer parens.  `for y in x.split(','):`

Comment: As an alternative, you can use a list comprehension like so: `comb = [i for x in data for i in x.split(',')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most performant: avoid `append`, `extend`: just do a list comprehension with 2 flat loops:

```
data = ["1,2","3,4"]
data_flat = [x for c in data for x in c.split(",")]

print(data_flat)
```

result:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: Why is 'for' prepended by ''x' in : [x for c in data for x in c.split(",")]

Comment: it's written the other way round: x is the element created in the loops described after it. list comprehension syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra paranthesis. Try

```
comb = []
for x in data:
    for y in x.split(','):
        comb.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the inner loop.

```
In [1]: data = ["1,2","3,4"]

In [2]: comb=list()

In [3]: for d in data:
   ...:     comb.extend(d.split(","))
   ...:

In [4]: comb
Out[4]: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. You had the `for` right on the first one. It seems that the parens after the `split` confused you and made you revert to another programming language that puts parens around `for` and `if` criteria. By removing the extraneous parens from the `for y`, you can fix it.

```
In [22]: data = ["1,2","3,4"]
    ...:
    ...: comb = []
    ...:
    ...: for x in data:
    ...:     for y in x.split(','):
    ...:         comb.append(y)
    ...:

In [23]: comb
Out[23]: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: Bruno ,bingo comment :)

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
print([item for sublist in ["1,2","3,4"] for item in sublist.split(',')])
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

But your code is absolutely fine.The problem was that extra brackets you gave in your for loop:

```
data = ["1,2","3,4"]

comb = []
for x in data:
    for y in x.split(','): #corrected
        comb.append(y)

print(comb)
```